# "write" transaction return values, any plans to make those easily accessible?

Tags: returndata

"write" transactions don't have return values, Events should be used instead, etc.

is there easy ways to make return values easily accessible to transaction sender? any plans to do so? (lots of features that have been missing ended up being integrated over the years. like, `type(uint).max`, last year, etc. countless examples, so asking in that context. )

Comment: AFAIK nobody has complained enough to create the proposal and code the implementation. If you are interested in the feature create the EIP and start coding the modification required to the clients.

Comment: what I'm interested in is primarily if it is easy, and if the feature is lacking because it just hasn't been the priority so far. if it is "planned" as in, highly possible down the road but just not done yet. and then if there are also any plans.

Comment: at the moment, for my smart contract, I just rewrote it to make the function that returns a value a "read" transaction, and moving the write-operation to another place. but still interesting to know what the long term plans are.

Comment: My guess is that is unlikely to be implemented in the near future because nobody has complained enough to do something.

Comment: k thanks, that answers "is it planned". what about if it is easy or not? I think the explanations I've seen are a bit contradictory. one is, "return value can't be received because transaction hasn't been mined", but, in a lot of UIs, incl. remix, I get receipts after transaction actually has been mined. it could include the return value. but, one reason not to, that I've seen, is that return value is of arbitrary size, and receipts might have more of a fixed format. any insight?

Comment: also, I adapted my code to make the write-transaction I assumed people would use to get the return value into a read transaction instead, so I'm not really complaining either at the moment. at first it seemed like a hassle but having it view-only is actually better..